# How does the Google Voice HTML5 app access the iPhone dialer?

Tags: iphone, html, google-voice

How does the Google Voice HTML5 app access the iPhone dialer given that it's not a native compiled app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably uses Safari's support for the [`tel:` protocol](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html).